# How can a SQL query have two from clauses?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This just looks so odd to me:

```
delete from GearsDev.dbo.Products 
from GearsDev.dbo.Products as C
inner join #Common as M
    on M.item = C.ItemNumber
```

`#Common` is a temp table, but the rest of it makes no sense to me.

How can you have two `from` clauses?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As can be seen from the documentation of [DELETE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx), it can take two `FROM` clauses.

The first `FROM`:

> FROM:
>   Is an optional keyword that can be used between the DELETE keyword and the target table_or_view_name, or rowset_function_limited.

The second `FROM`:

> `FROM <table_source>`:
>   Specifies an additional FROM clause. This Transact-SQL extension to DELETE allows specifying data from  and deleting the corresponding rows from the table in the first FROM clause.
>
> This extension, specifying a join, can be used instead of a subquery in the WHERE clause to identify rows to be removed.

So, the SQL will delete records from the `Products` table that have a matching item when it is joined with `#common`.

This is equivalent (in meaning) to the following query:

```
delete from [GearsDev].[dbo].[Products]
where ItemNumber in
(
  select item from #common
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can constrain the set of records you want to delete by more than one table. The second `from` just generates the alias `C` for the table you delete from, joins it with the table `#common` and deletes only records which have a record in talbe `#common`.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx)  The second from allows you create a filter that corresponding rows in the first from are deleted where they match.

In this case Delete all [GearsDev].[dbo].[Products] where ItemNumber has a corresponding row in #Common with the item of the same value