# Why does this delete statement work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, delete-row

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can a SQL query have two from clauses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011197/how-can-a-sql-query-have-two-from-clauses)

```
delete from machine_placement_group
from (machine_group g
left  join config_chg_req r
   on g.machine_group_id = r.machine_group_id)
join machine_placement_group mg
  on g.machine_group_id = mg.machine_group_id
```

I don't understand the two from statements.

Comment: Looks like SQL Server syntax to me.

Comment: @Yuck I have never seen SQL Server syntax with two from clauses in a delete

Comment: Yes, it's SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: @bluefeet FYI http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx The syntax supports this type of `DELETE`. Definitely SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

To quote [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx) for the *second* FROM:

> FROM table_source
>
> Specifies an additional FROM clause. **This Transact-SQL extension to DELETE allows 
>    specifying data from `<table_source>` and deleting the
>    corresponding rows from the table in the first FROM clause.**
>
> This extension, specifying a join, can be used instead of a subquery in the WHERE clause
>    to identify rows to be removed.
>
> For more information, see [FROM (Transact-SQL).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx)

So basically it does what it says on the tin. You specify an additional result set from which the data to be deleted in the original table is determined.

Answer (score 1):

The first from is optional, the second one is not.

For instance you can write

```
delete from table1 where id = 10
```

or

```
delete table1 where id = 10
```

But if you are joining to other tables as this query is you need that second FROM.

My preferred style for things like this is to use the alias, so I would write.

```
delete g
--select *
from machine_group g
left  join config_chg_req r
   on g.machine_group_id = r.machine_group_id
join machine_placement_group mg
  on g.machine_group_id = mg.machine_group_id
```

You note how I embed a select in the statement, this allows you to see what records will be deleted before you run the report by running just from Select to the end of the query

Answer (score 0):

I think it could also be written as

```
delete machine_placement_group
from machine_group g
left  join config_chg_req r
   on g.machine_group_id = r.machine_group_id
join machine_placement_group mg
  on g.machine_group_id = mg.machine_group_id
```

and works as a valid statement like

```
Declare @Test Table (id int)
insert into @Test values(1)

delete   dbo.Employee 
from  @test g
join dbo.Employee e on g.id=e.ID
```

where any row is deleted FROM @test fitting the joining condition
like

```
delete   dbo.Employee 
from  @test g
```

Comment: I think I get it now.  It's going to delete every row in machine_placement_group where there is a matching row in machine_group by machine_group_id and a row in config_chg_req by machine_group_id.  Delete a row in table a if corresponding rows exit in tables b and c.  How did I do?